# How to add header banner to a external website and display after loading using extensions in background for loading js files

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

After loading some purticular sites i must be able to add my own defined header banner to that site and display site. This loading can be made possible with running js files in background after loading site. But how to edit site in js add my extra banner to that site. I am adding here a sample pic how banner should be added at the top of site.
[image]

like that above banner should be added automatically after loading some sites.
for example this is  the code of header i should place on site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.wetest{
background-color:black;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
li a{
text-decoration:none;
padding:14px 16px;
color:white;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
}
li a:hover{
background-color:orange;
}
.litest{
display:inline;
float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="wetest"><span style="cursor:pointer">
<li class="litest"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li class="litest"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li class="litest"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li class="litest"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</span>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried for this so far?

Comment: To modify a web page you need a *content script*, see [the architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: @billy.farroll I updated my code in post. Thanks for helpingl.